# What kind of ipn response is recieved on subscription deactivation from within paypal?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I am first charging my customers for instant payment, and then creating a subscription profile. here is the ipn i recieve.

**I Guess this is for instant payment:**

```
[2016-10-31 16:26:11] local.INFO: IPN RESPONSE:Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 9.99
    [invoice] => 49
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [item_number1] => 
    [payer_id] => FA5XLVU3CLN92
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payment_date] => 09:26:06 Oct 31, 2016 PDT
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [mc_shipping] => 0.00
    [mc_handling] => 0.00
    [first_name] => omer
    [mc_fee] => 0.59
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [custom] => 
    [payer_status] => verified
    [business] => business@gmail.com
    [num_cart_items] => 1
    [mc_handling1] => 0.00
    [verify_sign] => A8SKEyFJtpw0I2pUVRQ9wRhpVLh9AnPjeq8ltcpWBhIHlTZuf.ak4aa-
    [payer_email] => customer@gmail.com
    [mc_shipping1] => 0.00
    [tax1] => 0.00
    [txn_id] => 3J610862594926351
    [payment_type] => instant
    [last_name] => farooq
    [item_name1] => Product 1
    [receiver_email] => business@gmail.com
    [payment_fee] => 0.59
    [quantity1] => 1
    [receiver_id] => RSDJM66ZP7LZ8
    [txn_type] => cart
    [mc_gross_1] => 9.99
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [residence_country] => US
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [transaction_subject] => 49
    [payment_gross] => 9.99
    [ipn_track_id] => af46df962d1bf
    [cmd] => _notify-validate
)
```

**And this one should be for the subscription profile:**

```
[2016-10-31 16:27:09] local.INFO: IPN RESPONSE:Array
(
    [payment_cycle] => every 12 Months
    [txn_type] => recurring_payment_profile_created
    [last_name] => farooq
    [next_payment_date] => 03:00:00 Oct 31, 2016 PDT
    [residence_country] => US
    [initial_payment_amount] => 0.00
    [currency_code] => USD
    [time_created] => 09:26:08 Oct 31, 2016 PDT
    [verify_sign] => AwD4sJJmdrzDKNGw7KMAMuZSx1AHAJkBGoIT8Zl86XtmqM9xpRo7woGm
    [period_type] =>  Regular
    [payer_status] => verified
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payer_email] => customer@gmail.com
    [first_name] => omer
    [receiver_email] => business@gmail.com
    [payer_id] => FA5XLVU3CLN92
    [product_type] => 1
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [amount_per_cycle] => 9.99
    [profile_status] => Active
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [amount] => 9.99
    [outstanding_balance] => 0.00
    [recurring_payment_id] => I-R159BJH8WJHF
    [product_name] => 49
    [ipn_track_id] => 45f60995a00
    [cmd] => _notify-validate
)
```

**Now my question is what if some one deactivates his subscription from withing his paypal account? Obviously i think i wont recieve an ipn response on the next billing cycle. Or does paypal send you something back saying that the subscription has been deactivated?**

Do i keep looking for whether ipn is recieved on a certain billing date, and if i dont recieve the ipn i just assume that they might have deactivated the subscription from within paypal.

Is this the best way of doing this? If possible can you explain how you work on your systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually did a write-up on this several years back, explaining all the different types of IPNs that can be generated for a subscription.  I've reposted it [on my personal blog](https://www.bahjeez.com/recurring-payments-ipns/) if you want to read the full answer, but here's the short answer: you'll get an IPN with `txn_type=recurring_payment_profile_cancel`.  This should happen as soon as the buyer cancels their subscription.

Now...if the buyer cancels in the middle of the subscription, you'll get a second IPN with `txn_type=recurring_payment_expired` at the end of the billing cycle.  For example, if you have a subscription that bills once every 12 months, and the buyer cancels after 6 months, you'll get an IPN with `txn_type=recurring_payment_profile_cancel` at the time they cancel it, and another IPN with `txn_type=recurring_payment_expired` at the end of 12 months (e.g., when it would have been time for PayPal to bill for the next 12 months).  The idea is that the buyer has paid for 12 months, even though they cancelled after only 6 months.  The `recurring_payment_expired` IPN is essentially a notification to you to say "hey, this person's subscription is up — now you should deactivate whatever product/service you're providing to them".

Comment: Thanks @matt, the blog post is incredibly helpful. I never thought there might be this many responses. I have a quick question though, does recurring_payment_failed mean that there was not enough balance in the buyers paypal account?

Comment: Not necessarily, because buyers can pay for subscriptions using other funding sources -- such as their bank account or credit card.  It just means that we failed to fund the payment for some reason.  (A declined credit card is going to be the most likely reason, but it's not the only reason.)

Comment: thats what i thought. Thanks @matt :)